# Getting a random image depending on ajax reply on a select box?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have a HTML select box like below.

```
<select name="item_1">
      <option value="0">Choose one...</option>
      <option value="1">Value (1)</option>
      <option value="2">Value (2)</option>
      <option value="3">Value (3)</option>
</select>
```

I have to do the following. Either way works, but I want to learn both, if possible.

**A.**

1. Imagine there is 3x different select boxes called item_1, item_2 and item_3.
2. Imagine a div (or a table) on any place of current document.
3. Whenever the value on select box changes, the div should contain a link to picture with option value.

For example, if "Value (2)" gets selected in "item_1" selectbox, then it should print 2.jpg on the div. If there are selected values in other selectboxes, it should also be printing their images.

Example: 
item_1 -> Value (2) --
item_2 -> Value (3) --
Output -> < img src="2.jpg">, < img src=3.jpg">

How can I do this?

**B.**

The same question as above, except; instead of directly printing the picture link depending on selectbox value, we will do a AJAX request to our PHP file. PHP will return the additional information about the selected value in selectbox. (e.g if you selected "value 2", it may get it's price, stock_count or picture_path or w/e from database.)

Depending on the returned values, we will get image_path value from database so instead of printing 2.jpg, it may print my_cute_dog.jpg.

How can I do this? I'll be glad if you can guide me.

Thank you,
Anil

Ps. No need to code PHP. Just give me the PHP file name, parameters and method. (POST prefered). I just need some basic jQuery/JS help, or guidance.

Ps. 2 You can name divs however you want.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Or are you just asking for code?

Comment: I would like to, but my knowledge is fairly poor when it comes to jQuery. Anything on PHP/HTML side is handled, except JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question is easy. Bind to the change event for your dropdown list. Then access `$(this).val()` to get the newly selected value.

You can then modify the `src` attribute of an existing image to be the new value. Note that I use `prop` here because I am in jQuery 1.7+. If you are not using newer jQuery then use `attr` instead.

Finally there are a number of AJAX methods cooked into jQuery. I chose `load`, but you could use something more complex like `get` or `ajax` for more fine grained control of the returned values. Load basically takes whatever is returned by the server and stuffs it into the matched elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/LHpJd/

```
//for select list with id of `select`
$('#select').change( function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    //directly set value as html
    $('#output').html(value);

    //change image url source
    $('#output img').prop('src', 'http://' + value);

    //change image url source from server (expected return value is something like <img src="" />
    $('#output').load('myfile.php?' + value);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use jQuery.
Lets assume this is your HTML.

```
  <select class="item_1">
     <option value="0">Choose</option>
     <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <select class="item_2">
     <option value="0">Choose</option>
     <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
```

**A:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handler for first select box
    $('.item_1').change(function() {
       alert('Handler for item_1 called.');
    });
    // Handler for second select box
    $('.item_2').change(function() {
       alert('Handler for item_2 called.');
    });

});
```

**B**
Yes you should use PHP or any other server side language. But I have a little suggestion / question?

> Depending on the returned values, we will get image_path value from
>   database so instead of printing 2.jpg, it may print my_cute_dog.jpg.

You didn't need to call another php file to get image path, just write all in PHP and return JSON encoded data to javascript. For this case I recommend you to add extra button, however this is optional. Lets write some code add this inside document.ready()

```
$('#get_data').bind('click', function() {

   // get current values from select boxes.
   var item_1 = $(".item_1").val();
   var item_2 = $(".item_2").val();

   //Sending AJAX POST Request.
   $.post("example.php", { name: "value", name_2: "value_2" },
      function(data) {
         alert(data);  // print data | you can use this data.
      });
});
```

Comment: Hello Vahagn Mkrtchyan, your reply to A is pretty clear. I can do the rest myself. 

It should get information of value depending on selectbox. This selectbox will contain over 200 items. (coding for a MMORPG) Once an item is selected, it will print it's stats with onHover effects. If the item gets changed in selectbox, then it will be replaced with new item values.

So, I believe in "Handler for item_1 called." area, we should be doing some nasty ajax requests. Will be glad if you can help! Edit: I also don't know how to print selected value in handler.

Comment: I just added an ajax function in my post.